# What does it take to buy a domain?

Tags: domain-registration

I don't have a particular server that I want to use for this domain. But I want to buy a domain. I don't have the name of the company that I want to register it to, because we are a start-up without name yet. I also don't have an address to register it to, except my temporary basement address.

What should I do? I really need to buy that domain, but don't want to make a mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just buy the name you want and park it with the company you buy it through. Then it will resolve to some under construction page or something that says its not up yet and you can point the DNS records to your servers whenever you bring them online.

Comment: Also, be careful that if you look up the availability of the domain several times, but don't buy it, many registrars sell the list of looked up domains to squatters, who will buy the domain in hopes of ransoming it to you.

Comment: I suspected that. so I just test to register `asdfasddfsd` domain in godaddy, but I discover that I need to provide a information like the company name. the problem that I don't have that information (they will change soon).

Comment: Is it OK to write that the company name is: `asdf Internet Services, Inc.`. or that illegal because we're not registered company yet.

Comment: Just put your personal registration info in there and forget about any company stuff. You can add that later if you transfer the ownership to an inc or llc.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy it yourself, personally, and transfer ownership/sell it to your business when you are ready. Same for the registration address.

Other than that, there's not much to it, unless you mean you want to buy a domain name that is already in use. Assuming you *don't* mean that then simply visit a good domain registrar and register the name through them. It might be worth considering if you want to go to a web host because you also will need to purchase DNS, website hosting, email, etc.

Comment: It's only necessary to consider a web host when you actually have content to put up on the site.

Comment: So, what address shell I put there? What company name? my home address? my temp location address? I just want to buy the domain. about the host, I don't have host yet. but I do ave a client dedicated server that I can temporary use. Shell I buy host first?

Comment: @David - yes, I'm simply saying that if the OP wants the "full package" it may be easier to go to a supplier that will do that in the first place than transfer later.

@ Stacker - Just put your own personal name and address in for the domain name. I don't operate any websites these days (other than those I handle for my employer) but I had quite a few websites for myself and for friends who needed my help setting stuff up registered to my name at my home address. If the form insists you put a company name, repeat your name in that space.

Answer (score 2):

Just register the domain and put in your own contact information for now.  If you don't want that showing up in WHOIS, use a registrar that offers a privacy service and none of your personal information will show up in WHOIS.  ICANN rules say that the WHOIS information needs to be accurate, but they will only take action on invalid information if it's reported to them due to some kind of abuse (which won't exist if the domain isn't being used).  You can update the contact information any time.